# svg placement within a div with media queries

Tags: css, ipad, svg, less

I have `svg` code nested in `div` that I'm using as links in a web page designed to be viewed full screen (chromeless) on an iPad, with media queries for portrait and landscape.  The `div`s layout perfectly in both orientations, but in landscape, the `svg` elements show up about 10px lower than they should, yet when the `div` elements get touched, the `svg` artwork magically re-positions itself to where it was intended to go.  In portrait mode, everything is fine.  What could be causing this in just landscape mode?  Could it be the css or the iPad rendering engine somehow?

The issue can be seen at [http://www.fmglobal.com/multimedia/airmic2014.html](http://www.fmglobal.com/multimedia/AIRMIC.html)
But somehow, this link only works when you copy and paste it into a new browser tab.

**css:**

```
nav svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: *"yet when the div elements get touched, the svg artwork magically re-positions itself to where it was intended to go"* Check if you don't have duplicate IDs in your HTML or SVG.

Comment: I thought that would be it, as I made the SVGs in Illustrator, where they all exported with an id of "Layer_1". I deleted all duplicate IDs, but it still didn't fix the issue, but thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this:

```
nav svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and it should work

Comment: Width and height twice?  Or is that just a typo? I was trying to throw in all the css rules I could think of that might be applicable, because I wasn't getting anywhere.